# Is there a way to unify Stack Overflow and these specialty sub areas?

Tags: discussion

Can I monitor it all on one home page and have questions posted to the widest audience? And receive and browse replies in one place?

It's too many channels otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Kinda sorta.

The regular way is simply opening multiple tabs. This also keeps the real-time feature alive ("x new questions").

The alternative, if you're going for the broad approach, is looking at the real-time feed. However, this includes all changes, and is for all sites.

If you only want to look at specific sites or tags, you can do so using [filters](https://stackexchange.com/filters/). You can set up specific tags or even entire sites to see in there. You can also look for tags globally (some tag on every site), or tags on specific sites (some tag on some specified sites).

Like I said, using the filters do unfortunately break the real-time updates, so you'll have to manually refresh it to see changes.

Answer (score 2):

Not really. They're distinct sites, with distinct audiences, scopes, and moderation styles. There's even folks annoyed with other site posts leaking over from Hot Network questions.  Lets break this up into several problems - since some are more mitagable than others.

> So I can monitor it all on one home page

Most sites have RSS feeds for questions and in theory you could monitor it all from an RSS feed reader.

> have questions posted to the widest audience.

Most SE sites are vaguely insular and have different, sometimes overlapping scopes

> receive and browse replies in one place

Notifications are unified and you can check those from any site. Alternately, while not actively maintained, the Android and ios Stack Exchange apps work well for that.